# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes

One of the big 7 questions.

- One suggestion per answer please

[Logo guidance, from Jin](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/design-ideas-for-gaming-site-updated-with-screenshot) (resident UI designer for at least some of the Stack Exchange sites):

> Please note: I prefer gray-scaled logo submissions, that way we can judge the IDEA of the logo more objectively. We can always add colors to the logo later. Also, the logo itself(sans the site title text) should be able to fit in a square dimension nicely. This way we can use it for favicons, mobile touch icons etc.

Comment: er... usually doesn't Jin, SE's graphics guy, start this question, since he's the one who will be making the question?  Yes, I'm aware this is one of the big 7...

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that springs to mind is a (famous?) playing piece in front of a deck of cards (perhaps the latter shouldn't be distinguishable as playing or specific game cards).

Comment: I was thinking one of the workers in Carcassone.

Comment: @Codemwnci - Agreed, a Meeple is a good idea, and recognizable, but I'm not sure about the legality of it.

Comment: A Meeple, that's what I was trying to remember. Thanks! That would have driven me crazy all night.

Comment: Power to the meeple.

Comment: +1 for meeples if we can get 'em.  There are a ton of third-party sites out there with meeple imagery and products so it may be legally clear.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to think of a logo that could convey both board and card games, while not trying to be too specific, or using copyrighted images.

I bashed these out in a few minutes to try and mimic a checkboard with playing pieces.

[image: Checks Logo 1]  [image: Checks Logo 2]

I then decided to add the four card suites, to show both board games and card games.

[image: Checks with Icons 1] [image: Checks with Icons 2]

Again, they're not much, but hopefully they'll get things rolling.  All constructive criticism is welcome!

Comment: It's a god start.

Comment: Too abstract. I'm a big fan of abstracts and playing cards, but I think we should have something with a bit more humor, which references more modern boardgames as well as the classics.

Comment: Also honestly there's some optical-illusion vibration going on with those color inversions that hurts my eyes.  I'll bet a checkerboard pattern could make a nice site element somewhere, though.

Answer (score 3):

A couple meeples sitting around a table, playing cards.

Comment: If well designed, it can work.

Comment: I like it, but if you don't know what a meeple is it might give more emphasis to card games.

Answer (score 2):

I [also](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like/157#157) like the idea of using both board and card game imagery.

My thinking was the most easily recognizable iconography for card games is standard-aspect-ratio playing cards arrayed as they are when held, and the most recognizable and still somewhat ambiguous game board is the chess and checkers board.

[image: B&CG logo]

It's gray-scale per the instructions and I put literally no thought into the typography, so this is just a conceptual design. Additional things that could be tweaked by a professional:

- spread of the cards
- relative scale of cards to board
- the absence of lines on the top and bottom of board, which are currently there to intimate that the board continues out-of-frame

Answer (score 0):

A big pile of spilled out random game boxes with some dices/tokens/figures in front.

Comment: I like the random game pieces, but not a big pile of them. Maybe a die, couple game pieces, and a deck of cards thrown together as if they just fell out of something.

Answer (score 0):

Does anyone know the copyright rules of using board game pieces in the Logo?
I like @Jon Hadley's idea about the cards and a board game piece, but not sure of the legality.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be a big king's chess piece for the logo. There shouldn't be any legal issues with it. It is easily recognizable and unambiguously liked to board games.

For the design one could add an assortment of Go, checkers and those generic cone game pieces, some dice or fake money bills.

Comment: sorry im new here, but that would crash with chess.se, no?